# Controls don't show over Winforms Host

Tags: wpf, windowsformshost, axshockwaveflash

I am trying to load a swf file as background for my WPF window. For this I have used a WinformHost and I load the swf movie in the Winform host using the plugin AxShockwaveFlashObjects.

```
<Grid>
    <WindowsFormsHost Name="wfh">
        <ax:AxShockwaveFlash x:Name="axFlash"/>
    </WindowsFormsHost>
</Grid>
```

Till here the application works fine. However when I add my other controls(buttons,textblocks etc) to the Grid, they dont show. All I see is just the movie. Any pointers please.

Comment: How do you add other controls to the grid? Can you show some code?

Comment: This is typically referred to as an "airspace" issue -- you can find out lots more by Googling for WPF and airspace.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is actually expected since the WPF elements are all rendered within a single HWND (that of the WPF Window in this case) and therefore are below the WindowsFormsHost (or any other HwndHost). This is discussed [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa970688%28v=VS.100%29.aspx) in MS' documentation and also [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms742522.aspx).

In theory this will be supported by some new functionality being added to .NET 4.5 - via the [IsRedirected](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.interop.hwndhost.isredirected%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) property of the HwndHost. This is discussed in some of the preview documentation for 4.5 [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms742522%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).

Comment: IsRedirected was only available in Beta, did't make it to final release.

Comment: As @watbywbarif mentioned the IsRedirected feature was cut so HwndHosts like WindowsFormsHost will always be above WPF elements. If you needed something floating above or something then maybe you can use a Popup as that is a separate top level (topmost) window but you won't get a sibling WPF element above the HwndHost.