# Make WindowsFormsHost layout under other control in wpf

Tags: c#, wpf

I have a application like following article :http://www.codescratcher.com/wpf/sliding-panel-in-wpf/ .In main I create a in center position .when left panel is expanded ,panel left is under WindowsFormsHost.How to set  WindowsFormsHost to over other lay out

Answer (score 1):

A `WindowsFormsHost` is *always* drawn on top of other WPF elements.

There was an `IsRedirected` property introduced in the beta version of .NET Framework 4.5 but it was removed from the final version as it had several known issues and currently there is no good way to make a `WindowsFormsHost` appear underneath other WPF elements I am afraid: [WindowsFormsHost is always the most top from WPF element](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9920480/windowsformshost-is-always-the-most-top-from-wpf-element)

Comment: I think you may have typed something wrong in your answer by mistake.  First you say that the host is *always* drawn on top, then you end by saying that there is *no way* to make the host draw on top.