# How to display CCTV from hWnd to ImageSource in WPF?

Tags: c#, wpf, hwnd

I have a ipcamera SDK (surveillance) that work well on WinForms. Currently, I'm using WPF MVVM.

[image]

I have try using `<WindowsFormsHost>` and using `PictureBox`, and it's shows but as I search, [these are actually explained why my overlay textblock is not viewing](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8010399/3436326). I had try airspace but got error and massive DLL are installed with AirSpaceFixer. I had to opt out.

Below are original design from WPF without WindowsFormsHost:
MainWindow.xaml:

```
<Grid>
    <Image
        x:Name="MainCamera"
        Source="{Binding MAINCAMERASOURCE}"/>
    <TextBlock
        Text="Camera 255.255.255.255 Offline"/>
<Grid>
```

ViewModel:

```
internal void OnWindowHandleAvailable(IntPtr handleCameraMain)
{
    CameraMain_Handle = handleCameraMain;
}
private IntPtr StartRealPlayCamera
{
    IntPtr RealPayID = NetSDK.NETClient.RealPlay(LoginID, ChannelID, CameraMain_Handle, EM_RealPlayType.Realplay);
}
```

MainWindow.xaml.cs:

```
private void GiveWindowHandleToViewModel()
{
    var viewModel = this.DataContext as ViewModel.MainMenuViewModel;
    if (viewModel == null)
        return;

    var windowHandle = this.GetWindowHandle();
    if (windowHandle == IntPtr.Zero)
        return;
    viewModel.OnWindowHandleAvailable(windowHandle);
}
private IntPtr GetWindowHandle()
{
    var window = Window.GetWindow(this);
    return new System.Windows.Interop.WindowInteropHelper(window).EnsureHandle();
}
```

I pass the hWnd of window to viewmodel to be use while calling the camera SDK. But the result, the camera is showing using the whole window since I have pass the Window handler.

[image]

I have 4 CCTVs need to be display on mainwindow. **How do I point these CCTV stream to targetted ImageSource?**

Comment: I am not sure what the question is but there is only one HWND in a WPF window.

Comment: Yes, that is my issue since WPF window have one HWND. The question targetting how do I display a CCTV stream to all image on WPF window as the SDK is require hWnd and it only show in WinForms. The target code is on ```NetSDK.NETClient.RealPlay```. It has callback, but I cannot view the image.